# Getting error EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY with a public key stored on Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, oauth, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm developing an external OAuth provider to be able to use our company login mechanism to let employees and customers connect to snowflakes.

### Snowflake setup:

First, I created a database for the sake of testing :

```
use role accountadmin;
create database fred_ica_db;
create warehouse fred_ica_warehouse;
create role fred_ica_role;
create user fred_ica_user password = '******' login_name = 'upn';

grant usage on database fred_ica_db to role fred_ica_role;
grant usage on warehouse fred_ica_warehouse to role fred_ica_role;
grant role fred_ica_role to user fred_ica_user;
alter user fred_ica_user set DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE='FRED_ICA_WAREHOUSE', DEFAULT_ROLE='FRED_ICA_ROLE' , DEFAULT_NAMESPACE='FRED_ICA_DB.PUBLIC';
```

and created the security integration object in the snowflake database like this :

```
  create or replace security integration fred_oauth_integration
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = custom
    external_oauth_issuer = 'http://$(some_endpoint)/snowflakeAuth/accessToken'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https://$(aws_account).s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/$(public_key_filename)'
    external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com')
    external_oauth_scope_mapping_attribute = 'scp'
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim='upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute='login_name';
```

### First attempt :

I created private/public key pair to handle token signature and uploaded the public key to AWS S3, which will also be our production target for this external OAuth provider. The file is currently available for grand public (checked on a public device).  The public key is in the form of :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKC...
...4oQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My OAuth server generates some valid JWT token (verified on jwt.io) + signature verified with public key :

(Base 64 url encoded)

```
eyJ0eXAi...wPgXvOtg
```

and decoded :

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
{
  "aud": "https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/",
  "scp": [
    "session:role:fred_ica_role"
  ],
  "iss": "http://$(some_endpoint)/snowflakeAuth/accessToken",
  "exp": 1632483169,
  "iat": 1632475969
}
{
  ...signature...
}
```

when executing :

```
select SYSTEM$VERIFY_EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN('eyJ0eXAi...wPgXvOtg');
```

with some token created by the system
The system returns the error :

> Token Validation finished.{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY"}

### Second attempt

(after @Srinath Menon his feedback)

From the public key, I created a json web key(JWK).  I created it using java code, and when I validated, I noticed it was also possible to use an online tool to do so.
https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp

I uploaded the result as a file on AWS S3 and made sure it is grand publicly available and that the content-type is application/json :

JWKS :

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","kid":"5979064a-e202-4321-90ad-8a51329aad61","n":"2636yeJSQqyO5AegaIu6vEHg6w-MzGy1nPy2qj0zJfbDw6O0ATGkG_ibdfWqMHxU-JEBV1wiThv8_Mk67cst4W5U-fg-Miy8SDxYZtIkWFMAeVbamjpi_8BChCIJRVXvS6ZQofGgmFHlJAnWszL0hID8IaHigpBLTNEVHKuPeVGTYg3RcoWTjjB3WtaIj8XqKpQY47EUOiHOa3DZISXteYlfZu9yhQdB-7s0kQhdzk-RiQIHsLfnn-ksVzntmmwHVE5KVllMJt-23bH8c1TbtrMzWHflY85K3iSjhB3EHyeqhZnKuhAR5WVxPxkGIdr9qku1Q6L489R1wRkE2Rk4oQ"}]}
```

JWK :

```
{"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","kid":"5979064a-e202-4321-90ad-8a51329aad61","n":"2636yeJSQqyO5AegaIu6vEHg6w-MzGy1nPy2qj0zJfbDw6O0ATGkG_ibdfWqMHxU-JEBV1wiThv8_Mk67cst4W5U-fg-Miy8SDxYZtIkWFMAeVbamjpi_8BChCIJRVXvS6ZQofGgmFHlJAnWszL0hID8IaHigpBLTNEVHKuPeVGTYg3RcoWTjjB3WtaIj8XqKpQY47EUOiHOa3DZISXteYlfZu9yhQdB-7s0kQhdzk-RiQIHsLfnn-ksVzntmmwHVE5KVllMJt-23bH8c1TbtrMzWHflY85K3iSjhB3EHyeqhZnKuhAR5WVxPxkGIdr9qku1Q6L489R1wRkE2Rk4oQ"}
```

Both these approaches resulted in the same error :

> Token Validation finished.{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY"}

Comment: Does this url "https://$(aws_account).s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/$(public_key_filename)" returns Content in plaintext format?

Comment: Yes indeed : 


curl https://$(aws_account).s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/$(public_key_filename).  

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKC...
...4oQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: In all probability that's the reason for this issue, the expectation is that it should be content-type/ json format. Is there any header information being passed which is causing the output to come in plaintext?

Comment: ok, I see, I overlooked the way the key need to be constructed.  I'll try to convert my PEM file to a JWS format.

Thanks for the tip. I'll reply with the result when implemented for people who will encounter the same question.

Comment: I still get the same error after changes.

The jws_keys_url endpoint now returns something like :
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"3064f813-2c8f-4d1d-8eb7-6cb32b3d82ee","n":"2636yeJS...kE2Rk4oQ","e":"AQAB"}]}

Checked that this jwk key can be converted to PEM and PEM can be converted to jwk key back on website https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp

I also made a test by stripping out the "keys" json container and by leaving the public key endpoint return 
{"kty":"RSA","kid":"3064f813-2c8f-4d1d-8eb7-6cb32b3d82ee","n":"2636yeJS...kE2Rk4oQ","e":"AQAB"}
only, but it gave the same result.

Comment: I also verified that the content-type returned by my jws_key_url is "application/json"

Comment: Can you post the exact full output from the jws_key_url for review?

Comment: Added full output of querying ${jws_key_url} in the problem description hereabove as it does not contain sensitive info. for both JWK and JWKS

Answer (score 2):

Got it finally working but changed my solution a little bit :

Created a key pair using commands (under MacOS) :

```
openssl genrsa -out snowflakeExternalOAuth.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in snowflakeExternalOAuth.pem -pubout > snowflakeExternalOAuth.pub
```

I extracted the public key content (removed HEADER, FOOTER and new lines) to initialise property *external_oauth_rsa_public_key*

I defined the security integration like this :

```
  create or replace security integration fred_oauth_integration
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = custom
    external_oauth_issuer = 'http://$(some_endpoint)/snowflakeAuth/accessToken'
    external_oauth_rsa_public_key = 'MIIBIjAN...hQIDAQAB'
    external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com')
    external_oauth_scope_mapping_attribute = 'scp'
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim='upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute='login_name';
```

I also noticed that I forgot to add some 'upn' claim in my token with the username previously defined ('fred_ica_user').

After those different changes, the system is working.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This is good information.